# Populate file revision to treeview

Tags: c#, vb.net, treeview, revision

I try to populate list of file revision to treeview. I have a list of revision file like a below.

```
1.17
1.17.1.1
1.17.1.2
1.17.1.2.1.1    
1.17.1.2.1.2
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.1    
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.2
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.3
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.3.1.1
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.3.1.2
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.3.2.1
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.4    
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.5
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.5.1.1
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.5.1.2
1.17.1.2.1.2.1.5.1.2.1.1
1.17.1.2.1.3
1.17.1.2.1.4
1.18
1.19
```

Now, I would like to populate it like a

```
1.17
    1.17.1.1
    1.17.1.2
        1.17.1.2.1.1    
        1.17.1.2.1.2
            1.17.1.2.1.2.1.1    
            1.17.1.2.1.2.1.2
            1.17.1.2.1.2.1.3
                1.17.1.2.1.2.1.3.1.1
                1.17.1.2.1.2.1.3.1.2
                1.17.1.2.1.2.1.3.2.1    
            1.17.1.2.1.2.1.4    
            1.17.1.2.1.2.1.5    
                1.17.1.2.1.2.1.5.1.1
                1.17.1.2.1.2.1.5.1.2    
                    1.17.1.2.1.2.1.5.1.2.1.1        
        1.17.1.2.1.3
        1.17.1.2.1.4                        
1.18
1.19
```

My idea is classified it by level

```
1.17         -> level 1
1.17.1.1     -> level 2
1.17.1.2     -> level 2
1.17.1.2.1.1 -> level 3
...
```

Then I use switch case to populate it to treeview

```
if level = 1 then parent node
else if level = 2 then child node
else if level = 3 then grandchild node
...
```

However, I don't know is it a right way to achieve my purpose. Is there any better way to do that?

Any help are appreciate and thanks so much

Comment: A tree is an inherently recursive structure. Building or traversing a tree, therefore, should be done using recursion. You can split your version numbers into arrays and then use recursion to treat all those with the same value at the same index as a group and traverse the whole lot recursively. As always, do it manually first to develop an algorithm, then write code to implement the algorithm.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That is a great ideal. Thanks you so much for your solution. Let me try to implement with it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the repeated pattern of the TreeNodes paths ( #.# ). Create an array of them using the RegEx. If there is only one item in the array, then the path is of the root node, otherwise string join the array except the last item (to concat the parent's name) and use the `TreeView.Nodes.Find(..)` function to find the parent node of each path.

▶ **C#**

```cs
private void PopulateTree(IEnumerable<string> paths)
{
    treeView1.BeginUpdate();
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

    foreach (var path in paths.OrderBy(x => x))
    {
        var node = new TreeNode { Name = path, Text = path };
        var arr = Regex.Matches(path, @"\d+.\d+")
            .Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();

        if (arr.Count() == 1)
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        else
        {
            var parentPath = string.Join(".", arr, 0, arr.Count() - 1);
            var parentNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find(parentPath, true).FirstOrDefault();

            if (parentNode != null)
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }

    treeView1.EndUpdate();
}

private void TheCaller()
{
    var revisionsList = //Get the list...

    PopulateTree(revisionsList);    
}
```

▶ **VB.NET**

```vb
Private Sub PopulateTree(paths As IEnumerable(Of String))
    TreeView1.BeginUpdate()
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()

    For Each path In paths.OrderBy(Function(x) x)
        Dim node As New TreeNode With {.Name = path, .Text = path}
        Dim arr = Regex.Matches(path, "\d+.\d+").
            Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(x) x.Value).ToArray()

        If arr.Count = 1 Then
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node)
        Else
            Dim parentPath = String.Join(".", arr, 0, arr.Count() - 1)
            Dim parentNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Find(parentPath, True).FirstOrDefault

            If parentNode IsNot Nothing Then
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(node)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    TreeView1.EndUpdate()
End Sub

Private Sub TheCaller()
    Dim revisionsList = 'Get the list...

    PopulateTree(revisionsList)
End Sub
```

The result is:

[image: SOQ60904806]

Comment: Thanks you so much for your detail implementation. I try and it's work perfectly what i expected.