# Vb.net tree view population problem with grandchildren subnodes

Tags: vb.net, datatable, treeview, populate

I have created a table (see image below) that I want to populate in a `Treeview` control.

[image]

`Mobiles` record is the root node
`Samsung` and `Apple` records are subnodes from `Mobiles`
`Note9` and `Note10` records are subnodes from `Samsung`

Using VB.NET, how can I do to populate a `Treeview` control ?

Comment: can you explain what you want populate ? Which columns ? All ? I have changed your question. Now, the picture of table is directly visible in question. But what you write about subnode doesn't correspond to what I see in table !!! Samsung and Node9 are subnodes of Mobiles, not Apple !? Can you improve your question. To help you, look how I have already changed it ;-)

Comment: Not clear.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61447227/10216583) for example.

Comment: Mobiles has two nodes: Samsung and Apple 
Samsung  has two subnodes:
Note9 and Note10

thx

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved using this code:

```
 Private Sub InitTree()
        'Populate table here.
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
        Try
            Dim sqlconstr As String

            sqlconstr = MainForm.Label1.Text
            ' CONNECTION
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(sqlconstr)
            Dim Da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select [Parentname], [name] from [dbo].[GR] order by [Parentcode] asc , [code] asc", con)
            dt.Clear()
            Da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    AddNode(dr("Parentname").ToString, dr("name").ToString)
                Next
            Else
                '   TreeView1.Nodes.Add("hgvzds")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        TreeView1.ExpandAll()
    End Sub
    Private Sub AddNode(parentNode As String, nodeText As String)
        Dim node As New List(Of TreeNode)
        node.AddRange(TreeView1.Nodes.Find(parentNode, True))
        If Not node.Any Then
            node.Add(TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parentNode, parentNode))
        End If
        node(0).Nodes.Add(nodeText, nodeText)
    End Sub
```