# Display results scraped from Webpage in Treeview Control from Class

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I'm working on a Visual Basic Project. My working environment is :

- Windows 10 32bit
- Visual Studio 2015
- .Net Framework 4.8
- Winform

At this stage,I have :

- Class (Class1.vb)
- Form1 (Form1.vb) with TreeView Control

I'm supposed to **Scrape** a webpage (i.e: **https://www.example.com**), I want to display the result of **Scraping** in a Treeview Control placed on **Form1**. I have tried some approaches and they worked fine, except that they require using **Webbrowser Control** which I do not wish to use. I found a method that I'm using now, but it seems to not letting me display the Results on the Form.

Here is my Code of **Class1.vb** *and it's working fine*

```
    Imports System.Threading.Tasks
    Public Class Class1
        ' Create a WebBrowser instance.
        Private Event DocumentCompleted As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler
        Private ManufacturersURi As New Uri("https://www.example.com/Webpage.php3")
        Public ManList As New List(Of TreeNode)
        Public Sub GettHelpPage()
            ' Create a WebBrowser instance.
            Dim webBrowserForPrinting As New WebBrowser() With {.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True}
            ' Add an event handler that Scrape Data after it loads.
            AddHandler webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted, New _
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf GetManu_Name)
            ' Set the Url property to load the document.
            webBrowserForPrinting.Url = ManufacturersURi
        End Sub
        Private Sub GetManu_Name(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
            Dim webBrowserForPrinting As WebBrowser = CType(sender, WebBrowser)
            Dim Divs = webBrowserForPrinting.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("Div")
            ' Scrape the document now that it is fully loaded.
            Dim T As Task(Of List(Of TreeNode)) =
                 Task.Run(Function()
                      Dim LinksCount As Integer = 0
                      For Each Div As HtmlElement In Divs
                          If InStr(Div.GetAttribute("ClassName").ToString, "Div-Name", CompareMethod.Text) Then
                          LinksCount = Div.GetElementsByTagName("a").Count - 1
                          For I As Integer = 0 To LinksCount
                               Dim Txt() As String = Div.GetElementsByTagName("a").Item(I).InnerHtml.Split("<BR>")
                               Dim Manu_TreeNode As New TreeNode() With
                                              {.Name = I.ToString, .Text = Txt(0)}
                               ManList.Add(Manu_TreeNode)
                          Next
                          End If
                     Next
           Return ManList
        End Function)
' Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
Debug.WriteLine(T.Result.Count) 'Result is 116
webBrowserForPrinting.Dispose()
End Sub
```

The above Code results 116 TreeNodes, which are the count of  Tags that I scraped. Now when I attempt to display this result on **Form1_Load**, nothing happens, because the Form loads before the Code finishes executing.

Here is the **Form1_Load** Code :

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ThisClass As New Class1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ThisClass.GetHelpPage()
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
        For I As Integer = 0 To ThisClass.ManList.Count - 1
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(ThisClass.ManList(I))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I noticed that if I placed an empty msgbox("") in the **Form1_Load** somewhere before **For..Next**, it forces the **Form1_Load** Event to wait and successfully populates the TreeView Control.

> What am I doing wrong ? or What am I missing there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***I noticed that if I placed an empty msgbox("") in the Form1_Load somewhere before For..Next, it forces the Form1_Load Event to wait and successfully populates the TreeView Control.***

Yes, it plays the `await` role if you keep it open long enough until the task in the `GetManu_Name` method is completed. Since the MsgBox is a modal window which blocks the next lines from being executed until it been closed.

Now, either you make it a complete synchronous call by removing the `Task.Run(...)` from the `GetManu_Name` method, or utilize an asynchronous pattern in such a way as:

```vb
Public Class WebStuff

    Public Shared Async Function ToTreeNodes(url As String) As Task(Of IEnumerable(Of TreeNode))
        Dim tcsNavigated As New TaskCompletionSource(Of Boolean)
        Dim tcsCompleted As New TaskCompletionSource(Of Boolean)
        Dim nodes As New List(Of TreeNode)

        Using wb As New WebBrowser With {.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True}
            AddHandler wb.Navigated,
                Sub(s, e)
                    If tcsNavigated.Task.IsCompleted Then Return
                    tcsNavigated.SetResult(True)
                End Sub

            AddHandler wb.DocumentCompleted,
                Sub(s, e)
                    If wb.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete OrElse
                    tcsCompleted.Task.IsCompleted Then Return
                    tcsCompleted.SetResult(True)
                End Sub

            wb.Navigate(url)

            Await tcsNavigated.Task
            'Navigated.. if you need to do something here...
            Await tcsCompleted.Task
            'DocumentCompeleted.. Now we can process the Body...

            Dim Divs = wb.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("Div")
            Dim LinksCount As Integer = 0

            For Each Div As HtmlElement In Divs
                If Div.GetAttribute("ClassName").
                    IndexOf("Div-Name", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
                    LinksCount = Div.GetElementsByTagName("a").Count - 1
                    For I As Integer = 0 To LinksCount
                        Dim Txt = Div.GetElementsByTagName("a").Item(I).InnerHtml.
                            Split({"<BR>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        Dim n As New TreeNode With {
                            .Name = I.ToString, .Text = Txt.FirstOrDefault
                        }
                        nodes.Add(n)
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End Using

        Return nodes
    End Function

End Class
```

**Notes on the method:**

- A single `Async` function to do the lengthy task and returns [IEnumerable(Of TreeNode)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1) to the caller.
- [Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) are used to add the [WebBrowser.Navigated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated?view=netcore-3.1) and [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?view=netcore-3.1) events.
- The [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netcore-3.1) is necessary here to wait for the completion of the [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?view=netcore-3.1) event in order to be able to process the HTML contents.

You need to add the `Async` modifier to the caller's signature to call the function and wait for the result. For example, the `Form.Load` event:

```vb
Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim nodes = Await WebStuff.ToTreeNodes("www....")
    TreeView1.Nodes.AddRange(nodes.ToArray)
End Sub
```

Or `Async` method:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PopulateTree()
End Sub

Private Async Sub PopulateTree()
    Dim nodes = Await WebStuff.ToTreeNodes("www....")
    TreeView1.Nodes.AddRange(nodes.ToArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm. I just need to get familiar more with some of lines of Code. Any other advices if I'm going to build more TreeNode Levels From this point?

Comment: @evry1falls Most welcome ya Basha. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61447227/10216583) for populating the TreeView part.

Comment: It is not the Treeview that I'm worried about Ya Negm, it's Scraping of Multi-web-pages, that should occur first before the Treeview. You see! Ya Basha, the Treeview is just for Testing purposes. This piece of Code and the upcoming pieces will work in a Background Process in order to compare/update a Database table records before the application starts.

Comment: @evry1falls I see Ya bo7maid. A `For Each Url ....` in the `PopulateTree` will do.  Or, make the parameter of the `ToTreeNodes(urls As IEnumerable(Of String))...` and make it returns a `Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable(Of TreeNode))` so you get key-value pairs for each page as key and a `List(Of TreeNode)` or whatever the type as value.

Comment: Wallahi Ya Jimi, I was just thinking about `Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable(Of TreeNode))`, I think it will be suitable for the scenario in my head. I will try to finish all the webpages scraping ASAP to finish this stage. Shokran for everything. May ALLAH bless you and keep you safe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ThisClass As New Class1
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do Until ThisClass.IsCompleted
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            'if the document takes too much time  
            i += 1
            If i > 30 Then Exit Do 'more than 3 sec
        Loop

        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
        For I As Integer = 0 To ThisClass.ManList.Count - 1
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(ThisClass.ManList(I))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
Class Class1
    Dim Completed As Boolean = False
    ReadOnly Property IsCompleted As Boolean
        Get
            Return Completed
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Sub GetManu_Name(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        'your code
        Completed = True
        Return ManList
    End Sub
```

Comment: @evry1falls , check it again , i made some changes

Comment: First of all, `Dim i as Integer = 0` won't work with `For I As Integer = 0 To ThisClass.ManList.Count - 1`, so I had to change one of them. Unfortunately the Code did not work either, and thank you for your effort.

Comment: I'm gonna have to try using `Async`, but I don't think it's gonna be easy with `Webbrowser`